# Is there a way to keep Steam from showing me non-game software for sale on the main page?

Tags: steam

Steam is now selling more than just games, and the non-game software clutters up the main page that shows new releases.

[image]

Is there a filter option or anything else I can do to keep Steam from showing me it's Software selections? I see that there's a "Software" tab if I want to see just the Software selections, but the corresponding Games tab makes me filter down to a specific category of games, whereas I want to see all games.

Comment: You could filter it by the category of the game your looking to purchase.  Outside of that the search results that Steam gives you cannot be altered.

Comment: The fix might involve yelling at Valve.

Comment: I imagine/hope Software will get shoved into a corner after the initial "Look we have software and Marketing told us to shove it in your face" period is over

Comment: there's a show by category option but there dont seem to be any specific filter to knock that stuff out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way of keeping Steam from showing you non-game software for sale on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Steam service once expanded beyond games, it disabled new submissions and voting via Greenlight. And now it is Steam Direct. Steam had claimed that it is currently not accepting any new non-game software titles for distribution except in a few cases for content-creation software from select developers.
https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/1500126447386593538/